# BroadcastReceiver.onReceive call many times

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I has two version `debug`, and `release`.

Here structures:

```
app/src/main/java/com/myproject/app/fragment/PaidInvoicesBaseFragment.java
```

Snippet:

```
public class PaidInvoicesBaseFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

simpleCursorAdapter = new InvoiceAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.invoice_list_item, null, dataColumnsNames,
                viewIDs, 0);
}

  @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();     
        initLogic();
    }

    protected void initLogic() {

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(NotificationsSyncModule.SYNC_ACTION);
        intentFilter.setPriority(NotificationsSyncModule.FRAGMENT_PRIORITY);

        getActivity().registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, intentFilter);

}

@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
}
```

`InvoiceAdapter` is in :

```
app/src/main/java/com/myproject/app/widget/adapter/InvoiceAdapter.java
```

Here snippet:

```
public class InvoiceAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

imageViewLargeSendPostalOffice.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(SEND_POSTAL_OFFICE);

                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
                }
            });
}
```

Here dubug version:

```
/app/src/debug/java/com/myproject/app/fragment/PaidInvoicesFragment.java
```

Snippet:

```
public class PaidInvoicesFragment extends PaidInvoicesBaseFragment {

    @Override
    protected void initLogic() {
        IntentFilter intentFilterSendPostalOffice = new IntentFilter(InvoiceAdapter.SEND_POSTAL_OFFICE);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
                intentFilterSendPostalOffice);

        super.initLogic();
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals(InvoiceAdapter.SEND_POSTAL_OFFICE)) {
                showConfirmDialogSendPostalOffice();
            }
        }
    };
```

When I click on `imageViewLargeSendPostalOffice` in `InvoiceAdapter` then it send broadcast `SEND_POSTAL_OFFICE`.
As result in `PaidInvoicesFragment` receive this broadcast.

Nice.It's work fine... with one exception.

When `PaidInvoicesFragment` is show and I minimize app and then return to app again and then click on `imageViewLargeSendPostalOffice` the method

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

is call once, but  in `PaidInvoicesFragment onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` call **twice**.

If I e.g. minimize app 2 times then `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` call 4 times.
If I e.g. minimize app 3 times then `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` call 6 times.
And so on.

But I need to `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` to call only once.

Comment: Why are you extends `PaidInvoicesBaseFragment`  ? and you are registering Local Broadcast in both fragments.

Comment: @MD PaidInvoicesBaseFragment  has common logic for debug and release version. How I can register only once mMessageReceiver in debug version?